# jquery validation, data is not saved in database

Tags: php, jquery

I have here a code of inserting a data in database, its working and doesn't have an error, but when i put my jquery code for validation of the data, my php code for inserting the data into my database is not working, can you please check my code. Thanks!

Here's my php code: `index.php`

```
<form id="FormToValidate" action="insert.php" method="POST">
  <div id="content">
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="csname" id="csname" style="width:250px" margin-bottom="3px"/>
         </p>
        <p>
          <select name="units" style="width:254px">
            <option value="option">option</option>
           </option>
            <option value="option">option</option>
</option>

          </select>
        </p>
        <p>
          <input type="text" name="color" id="color" style="width:250px"/>
        </p>


      <p>
        <input type="text" name="consticker" id="consticker" style="width:250px"/>
      </p>
      <p>
        <select name="mp" style="width:254px">
          <option value="name">name</option>

        </select>
      </p>
        <p>
          <select name="grm" style="width:254px">
            <option value="name">name</option>

          </select>
        </p>
        <p><select name="typeoftransact" style="width:254px">
<option value="type">type</option>

</select></p>
      <p>
        <input name="dp" type="dp" style="width:250px" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <input name="amount" type="amount" style="width:250px" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <input name="dirate" type="dirate" style="width:250px" />
      </p>
      <p align="right">AMNT PAID: </p>
<p>NEXT</p>
</div>

    <div id="secondary">
      <p>VSI No.:</p>
        <p>DATE:</p>
        <p>&nbsp; </p>
      <p>TYPE OF SUBSIDY 1:</p>
        <p>TYPE OF SUBSIDY 2:</p>
        <p>TYPE OF SUBSIDY 3:</p>
        <p>TYPE OF SUBSIDY 4:</p>
        <p>TYPE OF SUBSIDY 5:</p>
        <p>CHATTEL MORTGAGE:</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>
          <input name="chapaid" type="text" style="width:120px" />
        </p>
</div>
    <div id="third">
      <p>
        <input type="text" name="vsi" id="vsi" style="width:180px"/>
</p>
<p>
  <input type="text" name="date" id="date" style="width:180px"/>
</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>
  <select name="type1" style="width:180px">
    <option value="option">option</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p>
  <select name="type2" style="width:180px">
   <option value="option">option</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p>
  <select name="type3" style="width:180px">
    <option value="option">option</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p>
  <select name="type4" style="width:180px">
    <option value="option">option</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p>
  <select name="type5" style="width:180px">
    <option value="option">option</option>
  </select>
</p>
        <p>FREE: 
          <input name="chafree" type="text" style="width:100px" />
        </p>
</div>
<div id="fourth">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>Php: 
      <input name="type1amount" type="text" style="width:120px" />
        </p>
        <p>Php:
          <input name="type2amount" type="text" style="width:120px" />
        </p>
        <p>Php:
          <input name="type3amount" type="text" style="width:120px" />
        </p>
        <p>Php:
          <input name="type4amount" type="text" style="width:120px" />
        </p>
        <p>Php:
          <input name="type5amount" type="text" style="width:120px" />
        </p>
    <p>COST: 
      <input name="chacost" type="text" style="width:120px" />
    </p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>

    <p align="right"><input class="small button blue" name="Save" type="submit" id="Save" value="Save" /></p>


</div>
</div>
</form>
```

and here is my function, `insert.php`

```
<?php
include("connection.php");

$vsi = $_POST["vsi"];
$date = $_POST["date"];
$custname = $_POST["csname"];
$unit = $_POST["units"];
$color = $_POST["color"];
$consticker = $_POST["consticker"];

$mp = $_POST["mp"];
$grm = $_POST["grm"];
$typetrans = $_POST["typeoftransact"];
$dp = $_POST["dp"];
$amount = $_POST["amount"];
$dirate = $_POST["dirate"];
$typesub1 = $_POST["type1"];
$typesub2 = $_POST["type2"];
$typesub3 = $_POST["type3"];
$typesub4 = $_POST["type4"];
$typesub5 = $_POST["type5"];
$chacost = $_POST["chacost"];
$chapaid = $_POST["chapaid"];
$chafree = $_POST["chafree"];
$type1amount = $_POST["type1amount"];
$type2amount = $_POST["type2amount"];
$type3amount = $_POST["type3amount"];
$type4amount = $_POST["type4amount"];
$type5amount = $_POST["type5amount"];

if($_POST["Save"]=="Save")
{
$query="INSERT INTO accounts (vsi,date,cname,unit,color,consticker,typetrans,downpayment,amountfinanced,dirate,mp,grm,typesub1,typesub2,typesub3,typesub4,typesub5,chapaid,chacost,chafree,type1amount,type2amount,type3amount,type4amount,type5amount)
VALUES
('".$vsi."','".$date."','".$custname."','".$unit."','".$color."','".$consticker."','".$typetrans."','".$dp."','".$amount."','".$dirate."','".$mp."','".$grm."','".$typesub1."','".$typesub2."','".$typesub3."','".$typesub4."','".$typesub5."','".$chapaid."','".$chacost."','".$chafree."','".$type1amount."','".$type2amount."','".$type3amount."','".$type4amount."','".$type5amount."');";

(mysql_query($query))

or die ("error!".mysql_error() );

}

header('Location: index.php');

?>
```

If i put this jquery code, my php code did not work, but if not, its works fine,
here's my `jquery script`:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.validate.wrapper.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        // 1. prepare the validation rules and messages.
        var rules = {
            vsi: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 7
            },
            date: "required",
            csname: "required",
            color: "required"
        };
        var messages = {
            vsi: {
                required: "VSI Number must be Inputted.",
                minlength: "VSI Number should be atleast 7 numbers."
            },
            date: "Date is requried",
            csname: "Customer Name is required",
             color: "Color is required"
        };

        // 2. Initiate the validator
        var validator
            = new jQueryValidatorWrapper("FormToValidate",
                rules, messages);

        // 3. Set the click event to do the validation
        $("#Save").click(function ()
                     {
                        if (!validator.validate())
                           {
                             return;
                            }
                        $('#FormToValidate').submit();
                         alert("Data Saved!");
                          return;

                    });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: `<p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>...` hurts our feelings and it's probably that you're not returning true so nothing is posted.

Comment: can you put some print_r in the if statement or echo locate the error or print the sql query copy and try to paste in mysql if there error in the query.

Comment: there's no error in the query, ive try it without the jquery and its save all the data, but when i put jquery scripts, the data are not save.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with the <p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>... i use that because i cannot allign my fields using css.

Comment: index2.php is for the search box, there's no need for me to post that.

Comment: im not good at css, that's why i do that <p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>...

Comment: and besides, css did not affect my code, it's just the jquery

Comment: It would not be a waste of time to spent half an hour reading up how to avoid doing it when you have the time. Same with `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`.

Comment: Are you seeing the alert "Data Saved!"? Because the page should be going to input.php by then. No errors in your console at all?

Comment: ok ok, i will read that, thanks. anyway, can you help me find whats wrong with my jquery?

Comment: yes, data saved! was pop up whenever i click save button should i remove that?

Comment: no it just shows `('#FormToValidate').submit();` hasn't been executed because a post moves the page on. Ah, I see while I'm tying this my answer fixed it.

Comment: thanks again, i will try to understand css so that i will eliminate my <p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>... and &nbsp; codes,.

Comment: ok. As much as I avoid inline css, in the first instance you could just try for example `<div id="fourth" style="margin:50px 0 100px 0;">`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.validate.wrapper.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

$(document).ready(function () {
        // 1. prepare the validation rules and messages.
        var rules = {
            vsi: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 7
            },
            date: "required",
            csname: "required",
            color: "required"
        };
        var messages = {
            vsi: {
                required: "VSI Number must be Inputted.",
                minlength: "VSI Number should be atleast 7 numbers."
            },
            date: "Date is requried",
            csname: "Customer Name is required",
             color: "Color is required"
        };

        // 2. Initiate the validator
        var validator
            = new jQueryValidatorWrapper("FormToValidate",
                rules, messages);

        // 3. Set the click event to do the validation
        $("#Save").click(function ()
                     {
                        if (!validator.validate())
                           {
                             return;
                            }
                        $('#FormToValidate').submit();
                         alert("Data Saved!");
                          return;

                    });
    });